# Can an input be "labeled" with a aria-labelledby instead of a <label>?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

Is the following valid per WCAG 2.0?

```
<span id="my-label">Your photo</span>
<input id="my-upload" type="file" aria-labelledby="my-label">
```

The OS X screen reader understands this, e.g. reading the label for the input when it gets the focus, but Total Validator complains as follows:

[image: Total Validator error]

You can try it yourself by running Total Validator on [this page](https://jsbin.com/wiwuso/3). Is Total Validator correct to report this error, or is this a bug in Total Validator?

(Obviously, in this particular example, I could use a `<label for="my-upload">`, instead of relying on the `aria-labelledby`. One could even argue that using a `<label>` has more semantic weight and should be prefered. But that is not the question I'm asking, as in my real-life scenario using a `<label>` can't be done.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aria-labelledby` is used to provide information to accessibility devices like screen readers. It won't be of any help if you do not use such specific device.

It won't give any information to 99% of people. So yes, Total Validator is correct to report this as an error as WCAG does not require to use a specific device. That being said, you can use the `title` attribute in situation where you can't use a `label` tag.

See: [H65: Using the title attribute to identify form controls when the label element cannot be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H65.html)

Comment: About H65, this recommends using a `title` when no visible text exists, which is fine with me, but isn't the case I'm in. I have a visible `<span>` that can be used to label the `<input>`. It just isn't practical for me to make that `<span>` into a `<label>`.

Comment: And what users or scenario do you have in mind where a user would be helped by `<label for="…">` pointing to the `<input>` but not by an `<input aria-labelledby="…">` pointing to the `<span>` with the label? Visually impaired users will get the same result in both cases from their screen reader. And other users will "see" the label close to the input and "get" both go together this way. Do you have other cases in mind?

Comment: Also, while this isn't a spec, on MDN, they provide an example showing how `aria-labelledby` can be used, and they are doing what Total Validator rejects, which I would take as supporting evidence that Total Validator is incorrect in this case. (BTW, it would be nice to have an answer from some folks working on Total Validator.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute#Examples

Comment: @avernet The fact that having a `label` or a `span` appears to be the same for your browser does not mean that it is the case for everyone. One can chose to use a specific browser implementation or a plugin to enhance visibility of a label when focused...

Comment: @avernet Concerning MDN and TotalValidator, they have the right to be less or more restrictive depending on their own feeling. The only concern you must have is finding the best way to satisfy everyone.

Comment: My question was in the context of WCAG 2.0 "spec". When Total Validator says the something is invalid according to WCAG2 section 1.3.1, they seem to be expressing more than a "feeling" ;). cc: @unobf

Comment: @avernet and WCAG/H42 clearly says that you have to use the `title` attribute when a `label` can't be used. `aria` is a second layer to help specific assistive technologies which can be used to improve other methods, not to replace them. (although WCAG tests are not normative of course)

Comment: I think you're referring to H44 (http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140916/H44), not H42. Yes, that is a technique to satisfy 1.3.1, but there are other possible techniques, including ARIA16 (http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140916/ARIA16). And each one of those techniques is *sufficient*. So you can do H44, or ARIA16, or both. But this means that doing just ARIA16 (just like doing just H44), as done in the example on MDN, is sufficient enough to satisfy 1.3.1. Are you reading this differently?

Comment: Sorry, it was H65. You have to read user agent support for aria 16 : http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/ua-notes/aria#ARIA16. It is only supported by some screen readers (i.e. for blind people), not for common browsers (i.e. for every disabled person except blind people). It is a subtle difference.

Comment: OK, would it fair to summarize your claim as follows? Total Validator is right to flag this as a violation, because if you have an element in DOM that contains the label for the input, then (a) you should you should use `<label for="id-of-input">` for that element (instead of, say, `<span>`), and if not possible (b) have that label in the `title` attribute of the `<input>`. This will ensure that the user agent knows what the label is for the input, even if the user agent doesn't support ARIA, and has virtually no drawback.

Comment: @avernet Yes. And if you want to add an example : someone with cognitive disabilities can have a custom browser CSS to highlight label of form fields. You can also add that `aria-labelledby` can be used in addition to add a different degree of precision for blind people

Comment: Got it. I am 75% convinced by your position ;), so will mark this as the answer, and will let others finding this page judge what they prefer. Thank you your time, and I will try to use a label or the title attribute in my own application.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to use `aria-labelledby` as a way of creating an accessible name where a visible label already exists. It is better to provide a label association using for-id because that will allow clicking on the label text to place the focus in the input field (or select the checkbox or radio button).

Your accessibility analyzer is old. If you use the [aXe accessibility analyzer](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/blob/master/doc/projects.md), you will notice that it will not complain about this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Could you elaborate on what you meant by "Your  accessibility analyzer is old"? I am using v8.8.0 released in July 2015. The tool is maintained, and the version I am using not "old". Was this a way of saying "your  accessibility analyzer has a bug", or did you mean something different?

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation in your answer: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior